# importing non JS files in Google Firebase Functions typescript project

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a Cloud Functions project initialized with Firebase SDK.
I chose typescript as a language.
I would like to import a non js, non ts file as a string, using `import` syntax. For example:

`import * as content from './templates/text.md'`

But obviously, I get an error:

`error TS2307: Cannot find module './templates/text.md'.`

How should I configure my project (.d.ts files? tsconfig.json? something else), so that it compiles correctly.

For reference of how the project is initialized with Firebase SDK:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't import something that doesn't parse as JavaScript.  Instead, if you want to get the contents of some other file, you should read it with something like [readFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback).

Comment: It is possible, when typescript is compiled with webpack (see: https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/#importing-other-assets). Is this not possible with tsc compiler?

Comment: Cloud Functions for Firebase doesn't use webpack or any other bundling system.  All the files are simply uploaded as they sit in the functions folder, except node_modules, which is reconstituted by npm on the server.